# I have a PayPal error on my live website...to do with Preapprovals

Tags: php, paypal

Sorry, I'm quite non-technical.  I have a live and working website that has been working for some time now.  I have made some changes today and now I'm getting an error to do with my preapproval.  I just need to narrow down the problem so I can try to fix it.

Can someone please help with this? Can you tell from the error what may have caused the problem?

```
Preapproval Response:

PreapprovalResponse Object (
    [responseEnvelope] => ResponseEnvelope Object (
        [timestamp] => 2017-02-03T12:23:53.502-08:00
        [ack] => Failure
        [correlationId] => 8b944d2d540c4
        [build] => 29031018
    )
    [preapprovalKey] =>
    [error] => Array (
        [0] => ErrorData Object (
            [errorId] => 560022
            [domain] => PLATFORM
            [subdomain] => Application
            [severity] => Error
            [category] => Application
            [message] => The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value
            [exceptionId] =>
            [parameter] => Array (
                [0] => ErrorParameter Object (
                    [name] =>
                    [value] => X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

Could not process preapproval. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

Comment: Can you undo your changes? What did you change?

Comment: I don't think I actually 'changed' the live code.  I've been trying to create new pages but those have been kept separate from the live ones.  I really don't think I touched the live code but it could be possible.... But I was hoping from the error, it would tell me what actually went wrong.  :(

Comment: Well it is saying `The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value`

Comment: But what does that mean?  I've tried looking up that error and it seems to direct me to input the correct Live App ID and not sandbox.  My website has been live for over a year and I've not used the sandbox ID for a long time, so not sure why I'm getting this error now?

Comment: Well that leads me back to what did you change?

Comment: As i said, I didn't touch the live code.  I just want to understant the error code better.  For example, does it have to do with the Live App ID?  As I didn't do anything to this, I'm not sure why this problem would arise now when I've used the same Live App ID for over a year?

Comment: I believe the Sandbox app ID is different to the Live app ID and they don't work interchangeably. If you are testing this in the sandbox then make sure you are using the Sandbox app ID.